# Touchable opacity on press not working inside SVG tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg

I have a component inside an `<Svg>` where I have a button (`<TouchableOpacity>` with `<View>`) inside the component.

While the button `onClick` worked fine standalone, it's not working when I wrap the component inside the SVG.

```
<Svg width={'100%'} height={'100%'} viewBox='0 0 360 243' {...props}>
  <Defs>
    <LinearGradient
        id='prefix__b'
        x1={'75.7%'}
        y1={'34.3%'}
        x2={'84.6%'}
        y2={'-9.6%'}
        gradientUnits='objectBoundingBox'
    >
      <Stop offset={1} stopColor='#2ff290' />
    </LinearGradient>
  </Defs>
  <View >
    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => {
      console.log('DSDA')
      }}
      ><Text>Click me!!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Svg>
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1050

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your svg with TouchableOpacity tag,
Like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        console.log('DSDA')
    }}
>
    <Svg width={'100%'} height={'100%'} viewBox='0 0 360 243' {...props}>
        <Defs>
            <LinearGradient
                id='prefix__b'
                x1={'75.7%'}
                y1={'34.3%'}
                x2={'84.6%'}
                y2={'-9.6%'}
                gradientUnits='objectBoundingBox'
            >
                <Stop offset={1} stopColor='#2ff290' />
            </LinearGradient>
        </Defs>
        <View ><Text>Click me!!</Text>
        </View>
    </Svg>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that SVG is at the top as parent element, disabling the accessibility to `TouchableOpacity`. This means the press command is unreachable for `TouchableOpacity`. In short use single parent element.

Comment: What do you mean "single parent element"?

Answer (score 0):

In any case where touchable opacity does not register press event, it may depends on where you import touchable opacity from. try importing it from 'react-native' itself, not some community modules

Answer (score 0):

wrapping your svg inside Touchable should able to make recognise touch for svg.Try wrapping it inside touchable component.

Comment: Is this an actual answer to the main question? Who are you directing it to?

Comment: I think you mean "If you do any wrapping, the wrapper must be a touchable in order to have the wrapped result being recognisable for touch. This is the solution to your problem, if it is caused by wrapping into something else." (That kind of phrasing is an "explained conidtional answer." which is a method for users who cannot yet ask clarification questions in comments, for lack of the commenting privilege.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30769499)

Answer (score 0):

Use **TouchableOpacity** as a wrapper for the SVG and everything that you need inside.

Answer (score 0):

Get touchable out SVG not a supported component atm

Answer (score 0):

```
<Svg width={'100%'} height={'100%'} viewBox='0 0 360 243' 
{...props}>
 <View>
<Defs>
<LinearGradient
    id='prefix__b'
    x1={'75.7%'}
    y1={'34.3%'}
    x2={'84.6%'}
    y2={'-9.6%'}
    gradientUnits='objectBoundingBox'
 >
  <Stop offset={1} stopColor='#2ff290' />
 </LinearGradient>
</Defs>
</View >
 <View>
 <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
  console.log('DSDA')
  }}
  ><Text>Click me!!</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
</Svg>
```

You can try this just wrap the **Defs** by View this could work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32761620)